# Normalization above 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

Why we don't normalize our database design above `3NF`. Why the anomalies handled by 4NF and 5NF are rare, and in which circumstance we normalize to 5NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal forms that are higher than 3NF don't apply to every relation.  It isn't that we *don't* always apply the higher normal forms - you *can't* apply them unless your relation has specific qualities that make them applicable.

It isn't that the *anomalies handled by* higher normal forms are rare, it is that the conditions which make these higher normal forms applicable are not necessarily common.

As to when you *should* normalize to 4NF or 5NF, the answer is "always, *if* applicable - *unless* you have a good reason not to".